# Why is this script giving a syntax error?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I wrote this script from a Youtube video tutorial to practice coding in python for bioinformatics. When I try to run the .py file in `Python 3.7`, I get this error `print "number of g's " + str(g)`.

The .py file and .txt file it reads is in the same folder on my desktop. I'm using Windows.

```
# First python program.
# GC content

gene = open("OCA2.txt", "r") 

# set values to 0
g=0;
a=0;
c=0;
t=0;

# skip the first header line
gene.readline()

for line in gene:
    line = line.lower()
    for char in line:
        if char == "g":
            g+=1
        if char == "a":
            a+=1
        if char == "c":
            c+=1
        if char == "t":
            t+=1

print "number of g's " + str(g)
print "number of c's " + str(c)
print "number of a's " + str(a)
print "number of t's " + str(t)


# 0. = convert to floating point
gc = (g+c+0.) / (a+t+c+g+0.)

print "gc content: " + str(gc)
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: `print` is a function in 3.x+

Comment: Because it isn't *Python **3*** compatible (only *Python 2*). E.g. *print* is no longer a statement, but a function (but that's a different error).

Comment: @CristiFati Why would that cause this error? This error message is about an incorrect `\ ` character.

Comment: @Barmar: right, I didn't read the error message.

Comment: You would get this error if you wrote `gc = (g+c+0.) \ (a+t+c+g+0.)` instead of `gc = (g+c+0.) / (a+t+c+g+0.)`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Python 2.7 does not yield your syntax error.

Comment: @Prune did you meant Python 3.7?

Comment: I didn't say "3.7".  My copy above says "2.7".

Also, when I fix the input problem (to a file that does exist), the program runs just fine with Python 2.7.

Comment: @Prune The question says that he is running the script under python 3.7 and hence we should try the code in python 3.7. As I did and I gave an answer showing to use print with `()`

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned doesn't come up when I run the script either with Python 2.7 or Python 3.7. Although another error comes when using **Python 3.7** `print "number of g's " + str(g) SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and since you mentioned it in the question you should change this:

`print "number of g's " + str(g)` // works on Python 2.7

to this:

**`print("number of g's " + str(g))`** // works on Python 3.7

Comment: That's another error, but it's not the one causing this error message.

Comment: Ok apparently there are two mistakes, can you point out which one is the other?

Comment: I don't see any reason for the error he's getting. I ran his code and I only got an error for the `print` statement.

Comment: Exactly that's why I suggested based on his code and after I run it to change it to print(..)